# Any mobile-friendly Credit Card billing solutions for mobile sites similar to Bango?

Tags: mobile, payment-gateway, payments

Are there any mobile-friendly Credit Card billing solutions for mobile sites similar to Bango?

The advantages of Bango I have seen compared to regular Credit Card solutions that make it considerably "mobile-friendly" are:

1) It does not require the user to enter their full name and billing address to make a payment. The user is only required to enter their Credit Card number, expiration date, and CVC code (if they are in the U.S., they will also have to enter their Zip Code). That is significantly less input than is normally required for Credit Card payments, which is a big plus on small mobile key pads.

After a user makes an initial Credit Card payment, their details are stored by Bango, and the next time the user needs to make a payment with the same Credit Card, they just have to click a single link and it processes the payment on their stored Credit Card. Needless to say, this is very convenient for mobile users as it is analogous to Direct Carrier Billing as far as the user is concerned since they won't need to input any details.

The downside with Bango is that their fees are higher than others, all payments must be processed via their site and branding, there is a high minimum ($1.99) and a low maximum ($30) on how much you can charge users, and you need to pay a monthly fee on top of the high transaction costs.

It is due to the downsides mentioned above that I am looking for an alternative solution that also does the advantages 1) and 2) above. Is there anything like that? I looked at JunglePay and they do neither 1) nor 2).

Comment: i think the low maximum may be due to the fact that you dont need to enter full name and billing address, as these again add another level of fraud protection, over just the card details.

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I work at Braintree.

[Braintree](http://www.braintreepayments.com) has all of the advantages you list for Bango, and more.

- You don't need to include full customer details.

  - In fact, you can charge a card with just a credit card number and expiration date -- though you'll get less declines if you include the zip code (for U.S. cards) and CVV.
- Credit card details can be [stored by Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/tour/vault).

  - We can also store other customer and address information, including custom fields.

Braintree also doesn't have the disadvantages you list for Bango.

- We have [industry standard or better](https://www.braintreepayments.com/pricing) pricing.
- Our minimum charge is $0.01 and our maximum is thousands of dollars.
- We don't make you use our site for checkout

  - You have total control over the checkout process, and host it entirely on your site, so you can maximize conversions.
  - You still don't have to ever [see or store a credit card number or CVV](https://www.braintreepayments.com/tour/pci-compliance).

Comment: Braintree is limited to just the US, Canada, and EU and even then it puts limits on the type of sites it accepts, so it's unfortunately not a valid alternative to Bango.

Comment: @Programmer I looked in your profile & question before I posted to see if you listed yourself as from somewhere other than those places, but you don't -- and there are also countries where Bango doesn't operate, and we do accept charges and currencies from your customers in other countries. I'm also not sure what you mean by Braintree limiting the types of sites we accept -- any company does that to some extent but we have all types of merchants of all sizes.